# Android foreground service for Bluetooth Connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, foreground-service

Good morning,

I'm developing Android app, which track user heart rate. So i have a question, will be good way
and practice to use the foreground serive if the application needs to connect to the watch via bluetooth and then track the users heart rate all the time even if the application goes to the background or user open music player?

Thank you in advance for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the point of foreground service

Comment: okay but you could have added this as a comment